# How to add translations to a custom extension?

Tags: refinerycms

I am trying to add translations to a custom extension named Post, but when I try to save a post I get an error.

I have enabled three locales (:es, :en, :pt). I have noticed when I open a a form there is not a default locale selected.

What am I missing?

[image]

Migration:

```
class PostTranslations < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
     ::Refinery::Posts::Post.create_translation_table!({
     :title => :string,
     :description => :text },
     :migrate_data => true)
     remove_column :refinery_posts, :title
     remove_column :refinery_posts, :description
  end
  def self.down
     add_column :refinery_posts, :title
     add_column :refinery_posts, :description
     ::Refinery::Posts::Post.drop_translation_table! :migrate_data => true
  end
end
```

_locale_picker.html.erb

```
<input type="hidden" name="switch_locale" id="switch_locale" value="<%= local_assigns[:current_locale] %>" />
<% if Refinery::I18n.frontend_locales.many? %>
  <label><%= t('.language') %></label>
  <ul id="switch_locale_picker" class="clearfix">
    <% locales = Refinery::I18n.locales.clone %>
    <% Refinery::I18n.frontend_locales.each do |locale| %>
      <% locale_name = locales.delete(locale) %>
      <li<%= %Q{ class=selected} if locale.to_s == local_assigns[:current_locale].to_s %>>
        <%= link_to refinery.url_for(:switch_locale => locale, :parent_id => params[:parent_id]), id: locale do %>
          <div class="<%=locale %> locale_marker">
            <%= locale_text_icon(locale.upcase) %>
          </div>
          <%= locale_name %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

in Post form:

```
...
  <%= render :partial => "locale_picker",
    :locals => {
    :current_locale => Thread.current[:globalize_locale]
    } if defined?(::Refinery::I18n) %>
...
```

Schema:

```
...
  create_table "refinery_post_translations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "refinery_post_id", null: false
    t.string   "locale",           null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
  end

  add_index "refinery_post_translations", ["locale"], name: "index_refinery_post_translations_on_locale", using: :btree
  add_index "refinery_post_translations", ["refinery_post_id"], name: "index_refinery_post_translations_on_refinery_post_id", using: :btree

  create_table "refinery_posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "post_image_id"
    t.date     "post_date"
    t.string   "author"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
...
```

Error:

```
Started POST "/refinery/posts" for ::1 at 2016-06-04 13:22:08 -0400
Processing by Refinery::Posts::Admin::PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MIHqOv9yCQWkIdS2dKInFbJQtX62+21iqqTDzBtSCOHfBr7TejNIOgQX6iJgI4TWVqa+DVjsemz1DgkhtIZFOw==", "switch_locale"=>"", "post"=>{"post_image_id"=>"", "title"=>"Juan", "post_date(3i)"=>"4", "post_date(2i)"=>"6", "post_date(1i)"=>"2016", "author"=>"", "description"=>""}, "locale"=>:pt}
   (0.4ms)  SELECT MAX("refinery_posts"."position") FROM "refinery_posts"
  Refinery::Authentication::Devise::User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "refinery_authentication_devise_users".* FROM "refinery_authentication_devise_users" WHERE "refinery_authentication_devise_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "refinery_authentication_devise_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Refinery::Authentication::Devise::Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "refinery_authentication_devise_roles".* FROM "refinery_authentication_devise_roles" INNER JOIN "refinery_authentication_devise_roles_users" ON "refinery_authentication_devise_roles"."id" = "refinery_authentication_devise_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "refinery_authentication_devise_roles_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered /Users/juan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-9e79b276891f/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered vendor/extensions/posts/app/views/refinery/posts/admin/posts/_locale_picker.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/juan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-9e79b276891f/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_image_picker.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/juan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-9e79b276891f/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_wysiwyg.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/juan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-9e79b276891f/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_form_actions.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered vendor/extensions/posts/app/views/refinery/posts/admin/posts/_form.html.erb (142.5ms)
  Rendered vendor/extensions/posts/app/views/refinery/posts/admin/posts/new.html.erb within layouts/refinery/admin (151.0ms)
  Rendered refinery/_html_tag.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/juan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-9e79b276891f/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_javascripts.html.erb (139.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/juan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-9e79b276891f/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_head.html.erb (207.1ms)
  Rendered refinery/_site_bar.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/juan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-9e79b276891f/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_menu_item.html.erb (59.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/juan/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-9e79b276891f/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_menu.html.erb (89.9ms)
  Rendered refinery/_no_script.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered refinery/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in translations but I think there is a quicker way to do it.

In your model you could have

```
translates :title, :description
```

and that would be enough. The whole locale picker is, I think, generated automatically once model fields are being translated.

There may be generators too, but I am not sure. Check the gitter responses.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't get this error when you are on some default tab.

Check if in your vendor/extensions/posts/config/locales folder are all languages you want. Maybe it's because it's trying to get the translation for a language that is not set (or just special keyword for translation you added only for one language?).

Look inside your en.yml and check if that content is set in all the others language files you want to use (es.yml and pt.yml).

Edit: Oh wait... And what about that error inside of the image field? What if it's trying to get the translation for image title or something but it fails because an image is not set?